# Problem in calculus

Tags: calculus, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\psi$ be a non-negative continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and differentiable in $(0, \infty)$ such that $\psi(0)=0$ and such that $\psi^{'}(x)\leq \psi(x)$ for all $x\in (0, \infty).$ Then $\psi\equiv0.$

Comment: What is the problem? Do you need to *prove* the result?

Comment: yes, I need to prof.

Answer (score 0):

**Intuitive hint:**

If you knew that $\psi(x) = 0$ for some $x \not = 0$ it would be easy, right? Why?

What we want to force is that some $\psi(x) = 0$ for a ver small $x$ so as to enable its derivative to exist and be $0$.

Consider the point $x = \epsilon, \epsilon \to 0$. Now think about what happens about $\psi(\epsilon)$ and its derivative $\psi\prime(\epsilon)$. Use the condition $\psi^{'}(x)\leq \psi(x)$ to show that $\psi(x)$ can't really *"grow"* and thus must remain $0$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that the function $f(x) = \psi(x)e^{-x}$ is decreasing on $(0,\infty)$.